# UIAlertView Shows two times

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview

Hope you are all doing good.

Where is my problem is concern one UIAlertView shows twice while executing the code. I have written it within `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` as shown following

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//Finding city Name from coordinate
    UIAlertView * alertForCoordinate=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Coordinate" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude==>%f\nlongitude==>%f",self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];        
    [alertForCoordinate show];

    [SVGeocoder reverseGeocode:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
     completion:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
    {

        if (placemarks.count>0)
        {

            CLPlacemark * placemark=[placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            currentLocationUpcoming =[placemark locality];

            UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Location" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"currentLocation==>%@",currentLocationUpcoming] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];

            [self.eventsTableView reloadData];

        }

    }];

}
```

As view appears First `UIAlertView` gets call and dismiss automatically then second gets call When I tap **OK** button of second alert and again first `UIAlertView` appears  . I am struggling with it since last 4 hours and some of the answer put here also not intended the context in which  I am working. Can anybody suggest me where I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Does `viewDidAppear` get called twice?

Comment: No not at all I have putted breakpoint within it

Comment: In the method, there are two UIAlertView and it will show twice normally.

Comment: @KudoCC- I have edited the question please check it

Comment: Since viewDidAppear called after creation of view (making visible the view) it might help us to see how you create, and add to view hierarchy this particular view. Maybe you add to subview plus show it as modal view (just guessin'...)

Comment: And I miss from you code the line: [super viewDidAppear:animated];

Comment: Would you tell us which alertview show two times(mention title which you have set)?

Comment: It's normal a .Xib file no extra view is added as subview on superview

Comment: @Foriger if this line `[self.eventsTableView reloadData];` executes, it may show two alertview. Because in this method, he write two alertview. did you see? But reloaddata method won't trigger `viewDidAppear` again..

Comment: @Mani- If I Change the order of AlertView then which one will be first position would execute twice. No matter I have written it within the block or not

Comment: @Foriger- [self.eventsTableView reloadData]; commenting this line also not helpful

Comment: @AshutoshMishra My question is like what , Is one alertview(outside block or inside block) shows twice or Two alertview(both inside and outside block) show at time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44693/discussion-between-mani-and-ashutosh-mishra)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have the first `UIAlertView` showing twice - the animation just makes it look like this because you are showing two `UIAlertView`s in a row. You're probably seeing Alert 1-> Alert 2-> tap OK on Alert 2 -> Alert 1.  This is because the `UIAlertView`s stack up if multiple are shown.

Think of it this way:  Alert 1 shows first but animates for only a very brief period until it is interrupted by Alert 2 showing.  Dismissing Alert 2 animates Alert 1 onscreen again, and even though it is still the same alert, it looks like it is showing twice.

Try this simple test case:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert #1" message: delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert #2" message: delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

You will see "Alert #1" for a fraction of a second, then "Alert #2" will remain onscreen.  Tapping OK on "Alert #2" will show "Alert #1" again because it was below Alert #2 on the stack.

Comment: Solution to prevent it ? Although your definition is quite awesome So I have up voted you :)

Comment: Don't present two alert views in a row.  It isn't a good user experience and Apple probably recommends against it.  Consider just making an `NSString*` with the contents of the first alert, and then where the second alert currently happens, present just one alert with both strings.  In general, though, try to avoid using `UIAlertView`s if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your second alert overlaping the first one, and after dismissing second alert, the first one reappears on screen.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIAlertView * alertForCoordinate=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Coordinate" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude==>%f\nlongitude==>%f",self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    alertForCoordinate.tag = 1;
    [alertForCoordinate show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0 && alertView.tag == 1) {
        [SVGeocoder reverseGeocode:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                        completion:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
         {

             if (placemarks.count>0)
             {

                 CLPlacemark * placemark=[placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                 currentLocationUpcoming =[placemark locality];
                 /*****************Second Alert******************/
                 UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Location" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"currentLocation==>%@",currentLocationUpcoming] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                 [alert show];

                 [self.eventsTableView reloadData];

             }

         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully I am talking about first UIAlertView. I already know I have two AlertView bro ;)

Comment: Similer like @sathiamoorthy. I want to know the reason not hack. Because using one bool variable I can also implement it . Isn't it. I want to know where I am doing wrong. This is the thing.

Comment: it's not hack, As UIAlertView is a control which has its own priority to display on screen, So when you call [alert show] method in a viewController, it displays with disabling all interactions on ViewController (except Buttons on UIAlertView). 
Here in your code the same thing happening, second alert view taking all the priority and disabling first alert , and when you dismiss the second alert the Priority shifting to first alert.

Comment: But I am still searching the reason why it's happening. I know your answer may work but it doesn't solve my quest :)

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue "UIAlertView Shows two times", but in my case it was because of coding error with long press gesture recognizer (different than original question, but may be useful for other folks that google uialertview showing twice).  inside method to handle long press, i called method to show UIAlertView.  my mistake was not recalling that handle long press method gets called twice each time user long presses (once for press and hold down, once when user releases their finger).  the correct code recognizes gesture state (code below).

```
-(IBAction)handleHoldOnContact:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        // NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan hold");
        //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
        // ...            
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded release");
        //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too get the same issue. To overcome this problem, i done the following things. Get the alertview as global variable. And then,

```
if(!alertForCoordinate){
       alertForCoordinate=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Coordinate" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude==>%f\nlongitude==>%f",self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];        
       [alertForCoordinate show];
}
```

After that, when you clicking `"OK"` button from the Alertview. set that to `nil`. Like the following,

```
alertForCoordinate = nil;
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: It can be a solution but why I would make variable global for this little thing ? Then this variable would persist in whole file life. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. you are right. But sometimes the same problem will not happen. Because of iOS 7. i think so. We dont have solution for this. Isn't it?

Comment: I am deplying it with iOS 6 not in 7 because the app is for iOS 6

Comment: very good. I am really sorry. You should try some other solution.

Comment: @sathiamoorthy- Yeah I employed your solution but no luck. I suspect that some internal call gets call first UIAlertView twice. BTW thanks for your support dear :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a case of duplicating a button, and therefore it's IBaction references, in main.storyboard.

I had a button that was styled perfectly in main.storyboard, so I alt drag duplicated it and attached a new IBaction to the viewController. I didn't realize it but when I tapped that new button it fired the IBaction for both the first button and the second button, because it was hooked up to both, as it was a duplicate of the first.

I right clicked the second button in main.storyboard, saw the reference to the IBaction from the first button AND the second, then deleted the reference to the first. Problem solved. What a nightmare. Hope this helps someone.